# Picking a range of latest files using their os status times

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way of picking latest files by specifying a range of time using `os.stat().st_mtime` library. Let's say for example I want to pick every file which has been added into a directory within a range of the latest last 5 minutes.

The code I have been using below only picks the most recent file using `os.stat().st_mtime` library, the `[0]` index is obviously picking the first file.

```
study_dir = sorted(subdirs, key=lambda dir: os.stat(dir).st_mtime, reverse=True)[0]
```

What I want to achieve is specifying a range of all the files received in a directory within the last 5 minutes for instance, not to specify the number of files using indexing or slicing methods which will limit you to a specific number of file(s).

So the imagination of the code I want will be like:

```
os.stat(dir).<All files that have been received within the last 300 seconds>
```

The whole code of what I want to achieve is as below:

```
def get_filepaths(directory):
    """
    This function will generate the file names in a directory
    tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each
    directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself),
    it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
    """


    file_paths = [] # List which will store all of the full filepaths

    # Walk the tree.
    
    subdirs = [os.path.join(directory, d)
    for d in os.listdir(directory) if
            os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory
            , d))]

    # Get the latest directory
    study_dir = sorted(subdirs, key=lambda dir: os.stat(dir).st_mtime, reverse=True)[0] 
    
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(study_dir):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.
            
    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory.

# Run the above function and store its results in a variable.
test_dicoms = get_filepaths("/home/wisdom/Desktop/CT_CONVERSION_SYSTEM/Dicom_files")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter by the mtime instead of sorting by it.

```
range = time.time() - 5 * 60
study_dir = [d for d in subdirs if os.stat(d).st_mtime >= range]
```

Comment: I guess something I didn't make clear is I am going to use the os.walk() function to walk through the files within these directories. So the function is saying it's not expecting a list of these latest directories, its only expecting a file-path or string object of a single directory. Is there a way to go about this, I want os.walk() to be able to walk through a list of latest directories. Let me edit the whole code above to make what I am pursuing clearer.

Comment: It's the exact same code, you're just getting your list from a different place.  Don't do the sort, just do the `if` to keep the ones that pass your filter.

Comment: File "/home/wisdom/Desktop/CT_CONVERSION_SYSTEM/CT3.py", line 133, in get_filepaths
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(study_dir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 342, in walk
    return _walk(fspath(top), topdown, onerror, followlinks)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: Yes.  `study_dir` is a list.  That's what you wanted, right?  You WERE doing just the latest directory, you want a list of all recent directories.  You can't use a list the same way you used one string.